# Packaging to Maven project

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-package

currently we are using **ANT** script to build the project and running jUnit tests. Now, we decided to move to Maven.

We have two web projects, **Core-Project** and **Sub-Project**. Now here it gets complicate. Their project is as follow.
[image: Project structure]
Now, If I want to add this **Sub-Project** to **Core-Project** then I will create a jar of Sub-Project with WebContent folder and put it into Core-Project. Now whenever I run Core-Project, we have one utility class which extract content of Sub-Project into Core-Project.

**Final(expected) project structure should look like this.**

[image: final project structure]

How can I achieve this in Maven? I mean how do I create a jar which contain some files located in src->main->webapp.

Comment: **1)** Your example has no directory `src->main->webapp`. **2)** What result do you expect? **3)** A simple Jar can be create with `mvn package`.

Comment: @SubOptimal I have updated the question. How do I create jar of web project?

Comment: Hm, you are trying to build a web project, copy it into a jar, copy that jar into another web project and unpack files inside when it is deployed? Sounds like  xy problem. Use "web fragments" to add files to your core project instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to rethink your architecture a bit. This answer may go beyond the scope of your question, but it's important to treat Maven as 'convention over configuration'. It is possible to achieve your layout using a combination of maven packaging tools, but if you restructure and follow Maven conventions, it will make more sense to people outside your project and be less work to maintain.

Suggested:

```
config-project
sub-project
core-project
```

config-project can hold the configuration for all parts of your application. sub-project and core-project can depend on this project and use it at runtime. You should package this project as 'jar' or 'zip' depending on the resources you need to make available to other projects.

sub-project should only contain the binary code common to the non-web based part of your application. It should be packaged as a 'jar' project and not be packaged with the config-project dependencies.

core-project should be packaged as a 'war' project. and follow the directory structure as suggested here: [Maven War Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/)

Keeping the separation between your configuration, your non-web code and your web code will take a little bit to get used to. There is an excellent archetype by Tomcat which generates a maven project structure composed of these parts. It is easy to generate and inspect: [Maven Tomcat Archetype](https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-beta-1/archetype.html)